# Calling a shared function to another class in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, class, function

How to call a shared function in one class to another class , here is my code,

```
Imports System.Web.UI

Public Class functest
    Public Shared Function callthis(source as object, args as event)
      'code goes here
    End Function
End Class
```

I have to call "callthis" function in an another class. How can i do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
functest.callthis(something, something_else)
```

Comment: Should i inherit the functest class in another class?